# File not found error when trying to create a pickle.dat file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle, file-not-found

I'm very new to python and programming and trying to use the pickle function for the first time.

My understanding is the "wb" Access Mode should create a new file but I get the following error:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pickles.dat'

Here's the code:

```
import pickle

name = ["What", "Hi"]
words = ["Dead", "Right", "Hall", "John"]

f = open("pickles1.dat", "wb")

pickle.dump(name, f)
pickle.dump(words, f)
f.close()

f = open("pickles.dat", "rb")

name = pickle.load(f)
words = pickle.load(f)

print(name)
print(words)

f.close()
```

Comment: But the first file is `pickles1.dat` (with a `1`...)

Comment: Probably just a typo? `pickles1.dat` != `pickles.dat`

Comment: indeed.. need to learn attention to detail! Thank you